# Should we provide unique or shared description meta tag for our website's web pages?

Tags: html, metadata, meta-tags

I am building a website using ASP.NET MVC 5. Now I want to provide `description` meta tag `<meta name="description" content=""` for my web site's web pages, since this tag can provide useful info for search engines.

How should I manage this meta tag?

Should it provide a unique description about each web page (for example the "About Us" page will have different description compared to the "Contact Us" page or to the "Home" page), or it is a description about our company in general so all the web pages will share the same `description` content? Or there is not a right or wrong way that controls my decision?

Comment: Take into accounts it won't be taken into account by Google for ranking and stuff. Otherwise, some page may have generic description about your company (About, contact, etc) while I'd put precise description on specialized page, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`description` is a standard metadata name [defined in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-description):

> The value must be a free-form string that describes the page.

So the value should be different for each page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But i think it is better to say that the description metadata is preferred to be different for each page,, rather than saying it should be different..do you agree?. since i can have the same description for all the pages and this will not cause any problem from the user/browser or search engine perspectives ...is this correct ?

Comment: @johnG: Well, if you want to comply with HTML5, the value has to describe the page (→ so it’s different for each page, unless pages are identical, of course). From the perspective of the spec, it’s a requirement ("must"). -- I wouldn’t necessarily agree that not complying with its definition could "not cause any problem" -- user agents might make use of the `description` values in various ways, and it’s concievable that some of these UAs could "break" (e.g., not being useful to their users; giving a lower score; whatever) if these description don’t describe the corresponding page.